# MySQL shows lot of connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, connections

I checked my MySQL process list using "show processlist;"and it is showed nothing, But I used "show status like 'Conn%';" to check the connections and it is showed me around 9K connections. Is there any issue on the server.

Please clarify about this.

[refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWEoB.png)

Comment: IIRC the `Connections` counter is total number of connections recorded since the MySQL server process was started, not the number of currently active connections. The number of current connections show up as `Threads_connected`

Comment: @HermanB - Turn your Comment into an Answer.  (I agree with both of your statements.)

Answer (score 3):

The `Connections` counter is total number of connections recorded since the MySQL server process was started, not the number of currently active connections. The number of current connections shows up as `Threads_connected`